# Is there a way to set Hide Sidebar on Preview as default?

Tags: macos, catalina

Everytime I open a document with more than 1 page in Preview it shows the sidebar. I want to hide it as default but I can't find the option to do that.

Is there a way to do it?

Mac 10.15.4 - Catalina

Comment: Does it not just maintain whatever setting was last used? That's what it does for me in Mojave.